# Include link to .pdf

Tags: cognito-forms

My client would  like me to use Cognito Forms on her site for users to register to the site. When a user receives an email thanking them for submitting the form she would like to include a .pdf document in that email.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To include documents in confirmation emails:

1) Go to Submission Settings in your form builder, and open your confirmation email settings.

2) In the dialog, find the Attach? option, and select Documents. By default, you will have two standard PDF templates to choose from:

[image]

3) Open the Manage Templates dialog to edit the basic details of your document, such as the file name, the description, and the form logo, title, etc.
If you want to customize your document further, select the blue Customize button to open your document template in Microsoft Word.

[image]

For more information about creating documents, refer to the [document merging](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/5/document-merging) help topic.